# Is my cactus dying?

Tags: plant-health, cactus

I bought my cactus about one year ago. I was surprised that it grew very fast and I thought it's fine. But it looked too skinny and after some search on the internet I found out it didn't get enough light. I changed its place, now it's near the window, but unfortunately there's not much sunlight on the street where I live.

In the last month the color of the top changed a bit and some parts look burned. Also the texture doesn't seem right. Is my cactus dying? If yes, can I save it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not look like your cactus is dying. However, I would recommend putting it in some new soil with better drainage and not watering it as much it looks like it might have root rot. The soil I would recommend using is miracle grow for your situation. However, if you are raising more cacti then it is recommended you make your own. Also, keep this in mind some cacti have a growing season and dry season so depending on your cactus type it could also be normal for your cactus.

Comment: Thanks! I'll put it in new soil. I water it once a month.